# PhotoSwipe 404 prevention with fallback image

Tags: javascript, web, instagram-api, photoswipe

I'm displaying some images from Instagram in a PhotoSwipe gallery. The problem is that if the image gets deleted from Instagram, I get 404s in the gallery.

How can I check if the image results in 404 and if so, display a locally saved image (as a fallback)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onerror` attribute of `<img>` tag

```
 <img src="http://www.somewebsite.com/image.png" width=640 height=640 onerror="this.src='/default.png'" />
```

if `image.png` does not exist, then `default.png` is loaded